# Why do I get TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.items.map') when removing a component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to delete an item component from a list on my React app but I get a `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.items.map')` error when the event is triggered. I can't see what is wrong with the code.

```
function _delete(id) {
  return fetchWrapper.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`);
}
```

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    shoppingService.getAll().then((x) => setItems(x));
  }, []);

  function deleteItem(id) {
    setItems(
      items.items.map((x) => {
        if (x.id === id) {
          x.isDeleting = true;
        }
        return x;
      })
    );
    shoppingService.delete(id).then(() => {
      setItems((items) => items.items.filter((x) => x.id !== id));
    });
  }
```

```
{items &&
  items.items.map((item) => (
    <ListItem divider={true} key={item.id}>
    ...
    </ListItem>
  )
}
```

```
<IconButton
  onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}
>
```

What could be causing it to go wrong? The item correctly gets removed from the collection on MongoDB.

Sandbox: [View sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-williams-0r4gd?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Great question, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide a complete MRE so we can further debug?

Comment: Thanks. I'll do my best to create a sandbox, but I'm not quite sure how I'll do it without my local API.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony, I think just providing an example of how you are trying to delete a component will do! No need to have the API, just focus on capturing what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've added some more code which may or may not be helpful. The code successfully deletes the item in the API but `onClick` of the button to `deleteItem()` it causes the TypeError. `shoppingService` is just the js to talk to the API. My `deleteItem` function causes a TypeError after deleting the item in the API. Does that help explain my issue or is there anything more I should provide?

Comment: I have two hunches on what the issues are. If you can pop a MRE into codesandbox I can probably narrow down the issue fairly quickly.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Have added sandbox above. I am having a hell of a time getting it to work without my API as the boilerplate I'm going from has a lot of seperate dependencies I'm still trying to work out myself. I doubt it's much use.

Comment: it was actually a huge help, I appreciate the MRE. Hope my answer helps, let me know either way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the sandbox, it provides more context and makes this solvable.

It looks like you are attempting to export your functional component `ShoppingList` and this is the culprit:

```
export { ShoppingList };
```

That is leading to the error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

This is because when you use `export { ShoppingList }` you are exporting an object, not your functional component. Thus: type error. This can be verified with:

```
console.log({ShoppingList});
```

Returns:

> Object {ShoppingList: function ShoppingList()}

---

To solve this, change your export command to:

```
export default ShoppingList;
```

---

<s>This solves your original question, but other errors occur now. This is likely because `shoppingService` is not connected to the CodeSandbox. If you run into any further issues, I can lend a hand with another question.</s>

I reread your question and took some liberties with removing `shoppingService` to idenitfy what is going on with your remove function. I believe what is happening is you are trying to edit an immutable variable `items`. Instead, spread the `items` into a new array and then filter-out the item with the matching id.

First clean-up your data frame to remove the duplicate items.items reference:

```
const myItems = [
  {
    id: "5f516ebbd8f4d11abe5919c8",
    itemName: "Bacon"
  },
  {
    id: "5f52e43e4dda46085f008aca",
    itemName: "Eggs"
  },
  {
    id: "5f57a3056a71a0143281c1a8",
    itemName: "Oranges"
  }
];
```

Here's what your function should look like:

```
  function deleteItem(id) {
    let newItems = [...items].filter((item) => item.id !== id);

    setItems(newItems);

    console.log(newItems);
  }
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-removing-items-m8thu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks. I'm now using `export default ShoppingList` but I still get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.items.map')` when I click the delete button calling the `deleteItem()` function. It worked before when I didn't have both `items` and `itemCount` in json response and used just `item.map`, but now it just throws the error.

Comment: Check my update! I dug into your code further and I believe the updated answer fixes your delete function. The issue is you are trying to edit an immutable variable.

Comment: It works when the data is as you have it in the cleaned up data frame, however the data my app is receiving isn't a const declared in the same file, it is json from an API that provides both items and itemCount in the same response. With the new delete function it does not delete the item on my API or update the DOM. Could it be that it isn't possible to have both items and itemCount in the same json response?

Comment: @anthony It is entirely possible. I see two options: (1) use this [adjusted MRE](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-removing-items-m8thu?file=/src/AltApp.js) that uses `items.items` or (2) filter your apiResponse to suit your needs; if you don't need `itemCount` then shed it before your component ingests the data.

Comment: I have your solution fully working locally now. I have rearranged my data to not include the item count in the json response. The simplified dataset works much better. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Anthony my pleasure, so glad to hear that this helps, thank you for letting me know!!